# Golang: concatination array of int

Tags: go

Initial data:

```
rawdata := []int{17, 23, 100500}
```

Result:

```
result := convert(rawdata)
expected := "1723100500"
```

What should I do with `convert()`? I have:

```
func convert(param []int) string {
    data := strings.Join(param)
    return data
}
```

but it is not work

Comment: "it is not work" really is not a technical problem description. Given you expect a string to be returned, why do you have `[3]int` in the signature?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have corrected the signature. But problem is `strings.Join` expected `[]string`, not `[]int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function `strconv.Itoa` or the `fmt.Sprintf("%d",a)`

So like this

```
S := ""
for _,i := range intarray {
   S = S + strconv.Itoa( i )
}
```